# MVC4 naming Partial View "_XXPartial" ..what's the expected controller name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Ajax.Actionlink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Register", "_RegisterPartial", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "userLogon"})
```

Is the expected Controller function "_RegisterPartial" ??
If so, what's the real need to have the word Partial and the Underscore ??

Comment: _RegisterPartial points to an action within a controller with that name. I think in this case would point to your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470331%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), and so the expected controller name is `Home`.

Comment: Home is defined on the actual params so I'm ok with that. I'm just trying to understand the name of the actual function inside the HomeController.

Also somehow the PartilView fills my entire page instead of replacing the div "userLogon".

Comment: @Developer, based on the overload you're using, it's going to be looking for a method named `_RegisterPartial`.

Comment: If your partial is filling the entire page it is probably because of the way you are returning it from your controller.  Consider using `return PartialView()` if you are currently using `return View()`